# PHP XML Get Error

Tags: php, xml, file, debugging, get

I wrote a PHP Application (that works) and I have moved it to a different directory.  As a result it needs to get a file from a directory above it, but the file must remain hidden, ie:

- Root
- --config
- ---users.xml (Permissions 600)
- --lib
- ----loginUtil.php

I have tried two different methods of getting the file:

```
    $xml = file_get_contents("../config/users.xml");

 Which returns the following Error:

   [13-Jun-2012 08:54:04] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(../config/users.xml) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in public_html/test/lib/loginUtil.php on line 18
```

and

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("../config/users.xml");

  which returns

    [13-Jun-2012 08:56:17] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

I have tried using the full URL, and that works, but I must then make the users.xml file public (as PHP is doing a URL Request).

What can I do to resolve this issue?  (Thanks for your help)

Comment: Didn't Work.  I have allready tried 777 and that doesn't work either.

Comment: are you sure you moved the CALLED file (for example index.php), not just the included class etc ?

Answer (score 1):

try setting the full path and not the relative

```
$path = '/var/full/path_dir/file.xml';

if(!is_file($path)){

  // if this is the is output then you need to check permissions 
  // double check the file exists also.
  // check the web service can read the file
  echo "FILE NOT FOUND FOR $path";
}
else{
  $xml = file_get_contents($path);
  echo $xml;
}
```